# Relative positional accuracy vs. registration error - what is the correct terminology?

Tags: accuracy, gis-principle, coregistration

I have several aerial orthorectified images that I am using for vector-based (points) change detection. I have calculated RMSE using sets of points on static landscape features in the images (e.g., an RMSE value for images from flight 1 and flight 2). In this case, absolute accuracy is not important, or at least much less important than relative accuracy.

What is the appropriate terminology to use when reporting these values? 
Relative (horizontal) positional accuracy? 
Co-registration error? 
What is the difference here?

I've always assumed that registration error implies that one image was registered to another, but after reading some literature where this is unclear now I am not sure.

Comment: The RMS (root mean square) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation is the difference between your hook points and their intended location... this also includes operator error if you can't snap to the points but does not include a measure of how accurate the world points are to their correct location, thereby being entirely relative. Orthorectification is different to an affine transformation as it takes elevation into account. After the images are orthorectified you can do subtle shifts to make them align better but this is not advised if the images are too different.

Comment: So the images were orthorectified independently of one another, then I made some minor tweaks to enhance the positional fit of two of the images to the image with the best absolute accuracy. I only care about getting values for the error in the fit between images to explain some errors in my change detection analysis, which uses point data, not raster data.

Comment: I've read other papers that use RMSE for this purpose, but they are doing raster based change detection and reporting the values as "co-registration error". I want to make sure I'm using the correct terminology, and I'm having trouble figuring out the differences between relative positional accuracy and co-registration error.

Comment: Co-registration and relative accuracy are the same thing. RMSE is just the method use to measure the average distance between several points on both data sources to give a measure of how well they 'fit' together. As you're detecting change on points you also have to take into account your operator error - try finding some well defined locations on each image that haven't changed (rail crossings, road intersections, memorials etc..) and use those to measure the registration error rather than the points that are expected to move.

Comment: Yes, thank you, Michael. I did just that. I just wasn't sure if there was a difference between co-registration error and relative accuracy and wanted to make sure I was using the correct terminology.